# windows 2003 does not answer WINS questions occassionally

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, wins

A follow-up to [XP Clients lose WINS registrations](https://serverfault.com/questions/208359/xp-clients-lose-wins-registrations)

I have now run wireshark on an XP workstation as the problem occurs. A request for "foo" goes to the AD server which responds with "Requested name does not exist" yet on the AD server itself it can resolve "foo" just fine.

Unsure what to do next. It's clearly a problem on the Win2k3 SBS box but I'm not a Windows admin guy :-(

Comment: you have two different resolvers one is DNS and one is WINS.  Clients react differently based on there client level.  Are you all xp clients or do you have a mix xp/win7/vista maybe mac's etc?

Comment: XP for workstations. We have got Linux development servers too.

Comment: on the xp workstation do a ipconfig /all, does the dns suffix search list seem correct?

Comment: Yep although we rarely use it. For us we say "foo" rather than "foo.company.local" as "foo" is statically mapped for us. "foo" by itself usually works fine and still does on the AD when the workstation receives a "Requested name does not exist" from the AD.

Comment: so can you do nslookup "foo" from a workstation?

Comment: also as an fyi, we don't call it the AD we call it the DC for domain controller.

Comment: tony - yes I can do an nslookup foo and get results. But then if I ping (during an "outage") it fails to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

A few Qs:

- Are you referring to the name as \\foo, foo, or foo.yourdomain.com?  Try it on the client and server, and post the results for each test.
- Are your DNS server(s) configured to refer to WINS?
- Is your DC running the WINS role; are you seeing UDP port 137 in your wireshark trace?

Cheers.

Comment: Simon: 'foo', not foo.company.local or \\foo. foo.company.local does continue to work even though foo on it's own does not on the workstation (until I re-register dns). I can't see why the DNS servers would need to refer to WINS? The workstations are clearly working most of the time, wireshark shows UDP/137 traffic with the WINS server / AD server telling it that foo does not exist until the workstation issues an ipconfig /registerdns.